# Push to an array from a subshell

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to populate an array from a subshell. Is this possible?

```
array = []
processes = []
limit = 10

File.foreach("/path/to/file") do |line|
  if processes.size == limit
    processes.delete Process.wait
  end

  processes << fork do
    begin
      something = so_something
      if something == something
        array.push(line)
      end
    end
  end
end
Process.waitall
```

If I do this, the array shows as empty after the Process.waitall. I want to reference the array later.

Answer (score 1):

When you fork a process, its memory is copied and is now completely independent of the parent. If you want to pass some data back to parent, then use some IPC (inter-process communication) mechanism (pipes, sockets, etc.)

Maybe, instead of forking, you want to create a thread instead? Threads can update shared state (and this is exactly what makes writing multi-threaded programs difficult).